# A triangle inside a triangle

Tags: mathematics, geometry, triangle

All sides of a triangle T1 are shorter than the shortest side of a triangle T2.
Is it always possible to put triangle T1 completely inside triangle T2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The answer is**

> no

because, for example, if T2 has side-lengths

> 50, 50, 99 (so T2 is isosceles and very flat, almost no area at all, one angle near 180 degrees and the other two near 0),

then a triangle T1 such as

> the equilateral triangle of side-lengths 20, 20, 20 will not fit inside T2, because the height of T2 is so low.

**More generally**, we can consider T2 with side-lengths

> $n$, $n$, $2n-1$ for any large $n$ (when $n$ is very large, the angles of this rectangle tend towards $0,0,180$ degrees in the infinite limit)

and T1 with side-lengths

> $n-1$, $n-1$, $n-1$, which clearly won't fit inside the almost-completely-flat triangle when $n$ is large.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> no.
>
>  Let T2 be a triangle with sides 20, 11 and 11. We can calculate its area with [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula); $s = \frac{20 + 11 + 11}{2} = 21$, so the area is $\sqrt{21 \cdot 1 \cdot 10 \cdot 10} \approx 45.8$. The area is also equal to half the height $h$ times the base ($20$); that means the height is $4.58$. An equilateral triangle T1 with all sides length 10 clearly won't fit in this T2.

Comment: Are you sure this is true? It seems to me that, putting the shortest side at the bottom, the width of T2 would be close to 1.1 for quite a way above its shortest side, and so T1 would have room to fit in there.

Comment: Sorry, right formula, wrong idea.

Comment: Now the idea is the same as my answer. You've included a rigorous proof that T1 won't fit in T2, but I've taken even bigger numbers to make it "clearer". In fact, by a limiting process it can be completely clear ... brb editing.

Comment: My browser missed that you posted an answer as well :)